# Converting string to float python N/A

Tags: python

I am using ystockquote.py and I am trying to retrieve information pertaining to a particular stock. It is possible that some of information retrieved from my code is N/A, like the line below:

```
properties['ask_realtime'] = float(ystockquote.get_ask_realtime(stock))
```

Since ystockquote.get_ask_realtime(stock) will return a string, what would be the best, elegant way to check to make sure it isn't a 'N/A' string? I have more lines that pertain to changing the string to float so I really need a nice way to do this.

Comment: And what should happen if the string *is* `N/A` instead? `None`? Nothing should be assigned? Other options?

Comment: I prefer nothing to be assigned because I am trying to get this information and put into into a database in Django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not define your own float-converter:

```
def float_or_na(value):
    return float(value if value != 'N/A' else 'nan')
```

or with the comment from above:

```
def float_or_na(value):
    return float(value) if value != 'N/A' else None
```

to get a NULL-value into the database.

Comment: If I were to have a list of floats and I order them, will float values that contain 'nan' be processed and be at the end of the list, assuming ordering is from greatest to least?

Comment: @user2548635: unfortunately not.  But you can easily order it yourself that way, e.g. `sorted(somelist, key=lambda x: (~math.isnan(x), x), reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [`try...except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) was made for

```
try: 
    #Code that assumes value is float
    properties['ask_realtime'] = float(ystockquote.get_ask_realtime(stock))
except ValueError:
    #Code that runs as soon as a ValueError pops up
else:
    #Code that runs only if try branch finishes successfully (optional)
finally:
    #Code that runs after try or except branch finishes (optional)
```

Some things to note:

- You don't need to specify an exact error for the `except` branch, but it is considered good form to do and helps prevent masking errors. If you want to handle multiple types of errors you need an `except` branch for each
- The `except` branch only runs if the specified exception is raised (or any exception is raised if it is not specified)
- The `finally` branch will always run regardless.  It is optional, but sometimes very handy
- Any lines within the `try` branch after the line which raises the exception will not be executed
- Any exceptions raised in the `except` or `finally` branch will be thrown normally

**Example**:

```
try:
    print 1
    float(val)
    print 2
except ValueError:
    print 3
else:
    print 4
finally:
    print 5
```

With `val = "4.2"` the code above prints

```
1
2
4
5
```

With `val = "a"` the code above prints

```
1
3
5
```